# How to run asp.net core app automatically after changes in c# files

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I am running `ASP.NET Core` application on `Visual Studio Code` on a mac. To run the app, I use `dotnet run` from the terminal.

Whenever I make changes in one of the `C#` files, I have to stop and restart the app by hitting `ctrl+c` first and `dotnet run` again.

I watched Pluralsight course of Scott Allen, where he uses `Visual Studio` and after an edit to any `C#` files, he just reloads the page and it shows the changes. I am wondering if I can do the same in `Visual Studio Code`.

Comment: If you make HTML or CSS changes you just have to simply save and refresh page, however if you make c# code changes you need to recompile.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think that [dotnet watch](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/dotnet-watch.html) should work. See the documentation from the link as there are various options. Here I copied the order in which this should work.

> 1. Add Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools to the tools section of the `project.json` file
> 2. Run `dotnet restore`
> 3. Execute with `dotnet watch run`

Comment: That worked, thanks..are the steps same for `Visual Studio` as well?

Comment: @akshayKhot - you might be able to do CTRL+F5, in a full version of VS starts the process without attaching the debugger. I am not sure about VS Code but maybe its the same.

Comment: it works but it is very slow - like have to wait around 5 sec - any change to speed up?

Comment: Starting from .NET Core 2.1 Preview 2 the CLI tools like dotnet watch are now part of the SDK